# How can I add a key => value element to the start of each subArray?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

So I recently got into this school project and now I have to deal with multidimensional arrays in PHP. My problem:

I have an array:

```
$arr = array(
           array('subject' => 'Deutsch'), 
           array('subject' => 'Deutsch'),  
           array('subject' => 'Deutsch')
       );
```

And now I want to make it look like:

```
array(
    array('id' => 1, 'subject' => 'Deutsch'),   
    array('id' => 2, 'subject' => 'Deutsch'),  
    array('id' => 3, 'subject' => 'Deutsch')
);
```

I thought of doing something like:

```
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    array_unshift($arr, array('id' => $key + 1));
}
```

But this doesn't give me the expected output. How can I modify my code to get to my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [`array_merge()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) the id to each subArray, e.g.

```
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    $arr[$key] = array_merge(["id" => $key + 1], $value);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, worked with:  
  
    foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    $arr[$key] = array_merge(array("id" => $key + 1), $value);
}

Answer (score 0):

You can itterate the array by reference and add the id element:

```
foreach($arr as $key => &$val)
{
  $val['id'] = $key +1;
}
```

Comment: I think since OP used `array_unshift()` in his attempt the order is important, so that `id` is the first element of each subArray, but I might be wrong.